# SocketException preventing use of C# TCPListener in Windows Service

Tags: c#, exception, sockets, permissions, tcplistener

I have a Windows Service that does the following when started. When running via a Console application it works fine, but once I put in a Windows Service I get the below exception. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Disabled the firewall, also tried adding explicit exclusions for the exe, port, and protocol
- Checked CAS Policy Config, shows unrestricted rights
- Configured the Service to run as an Administrator Account, Local System, Local Service, and Network Service, each with the same result
- Tried different ports
- Also tried 127.0.0.1 just to see... same issue

This is wrecking my head, so any help would be greatly appreciated:

The Code:

```
var _listener = new TcpListener(endpoint); //192.168.2.2:20000
_listener.Start();
```

The resulting Exception:

```
Service cannot be started. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at Server.RequestHandler.StartServicingRequests(IPEndPoint endpoint)
   at Server.Server.StartServer(String[] args)
   at Server.Server.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to configure the endpoint ? 
There is more information here but I'm not sure it will help you
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819124

Comment: Sure, the endpoint was set using "new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(args[0]), Convert.ToInt32(args[1]))". These arguments are passed in via the Service Control Panel, and I have confirmed the local machines IP Address is set to 192.168.2.2 and the port is set to 20000, although I have tried other ports as well.

Comment: What operating system is this that you are running on? Which version of the .NET framework? Also, can you make sure that there is no kernel mode or usermode process bound to that port (netstat -n -a -P TCP) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you bind to an endpoint with IPAddress.Any (0.0.0.0) and a specific port.

The error message is likely because another application already has that port open or has recently had it open [exclusively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150667(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: IPAddress.Any is actually 0.0.0.0

Comment: You are of course correct! I have no idea why I put the broadcast value instead of the any value...

Answer (score 0):

More information on the error code is [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(v=VS.85).aspx#winsock.wsaeacces_2).